# React updating ref programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a structure of an input and a container for it that grows (auto-expanding text area).
The input container is in **absolute** position, and I need to know that container's offsetHeight at all times. For that I use `useRef`.

So structure looks something like

```
const [text, setText] = useState('')
const handleTextChange = (e) => setText(e.target.value)
const ref = useRef(null)
const offsetHeight = ref.current && ref.current.offsetHeight || 70
return (
  <div className="root">
    <SomethingFancy offsetHeight={offsetHeight}>{offsetHeight} 
    </SomethingFancy>
    <div className="input-container-absolute-position" ref={ref} 
    style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0 }}>
      <textarea onChange={handleTextChange} value={text} />
    </div>
</div>
```

What works:

- If I type any text and a new line is added onto input's height the .offsetHeight is updated, working perfectly.

What is broken:

- If I remove text: I had 2 lines of text with `offsetHeight=100px`, removing text makes it 1 line (`70px`), but changes are not applied to `<SomethingFancy />`.

Comment: I think this question should be editted to add explanation what <somethingFancy /> also, by absoulte position you mean that it has css property position:absolute?

Comment: somethingFancy is out of context here, and doesn't not require any attention besides its somehow needing the offsetHeight value. It can just be a div that just displays text offsetHeight. an yes 'absolute-position' is CSS position: absolute;

Comment: I took your code (changed some stuff that prevented it from working) and uploaded it to codepen, please take a look and let know if any changes needed to be done there, so I'll have easier time helping you out :)  https://codepen.io/bar-shopen/pen/QWKPvJW?editors=0010

Comment: The code example I have is not 1:1 of what I am facing, there's a bit more to it, like CSS properties to make textarea auto expand

Comment: You say you have a _textarea auto expand_. This is an important part to answer the question. I guess your component does not re-render after the textarea was expanded, but only when the next `setText` happens (`setText` -> re-render -> resize textarea ).

Comment: ok, went with a hack. To update it I just setText(prev => `${prev} `) (add empty space, and then remove it)